# New ios app not showing on itunes connect once being uploaded

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, ipa

As usual, i upload new version in itunesconnect via XCode 8 (recently updated). It is usually shown in the Activity tab as "processing" and then once uploaded it's visible there, but not this time. My version and build number match.

http://prnt.sc/cke2op - successfully uploaded 2.3.2

http://prnt.sc/cke2jf - 2.3.2 upload processing

http://prnt.sc/cke394 - 2.3.2 disappears once uploaded

http://prntscr.com/cke4g8 - 2.3.2 - registered as new version

I've done many times and it was working so far, may be there is some problem with my update to ios 10 and xcode 8.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same trouble here. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. Seems that apple sends an email with the issues which are disabling/hiding the build on itunesconnect Activity tab, however i didn't have access to that email so i wasn't aware of this. 
There are new ios 10 requirements which need to be applied in the plist in order to fix this issue.
For my app these were:

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.